# Ошибка запуска контейнера на Docker в windows 11

Tags: docker, windows-11

Я новичок в докер! Первый день знакомлюсь с ним. Установил Docker Desktop для windows с официального сайта докер. Затем столкнулся с ошибкой в приложении, где было написано "Docker Failed to Start...". На англоязычном форуме узнал, что победить эту ошибку можно через команду в консоли:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe' -SwitchDaemon
```

Однако, появилась новая проблема. Когда я в консоли пытаюсь ввести команду:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started
```

Выдает ошибку:

> Error response from daemon: open \.\pipe\docker_engine_windows: The
> system cannot find the file specified. See 'docker run --help'.

Как победить ошибку и нормально работать с докером? Что не так с daemon docker?

P.S. В трее отображается значок докера, и меню там также видно.

Comment: а у вас Docker Desktop вообще запущен? в tray есть иконка докера?

Comment: @ExplodingKitten, да, конечно, запущен. В трее есть иконка, и приложение открыто. В консоли пытаюсь выполнить команду по созданию контейнера (дефолтная команда от приложения). Может антивирус это мешать или служба может какая-то не запущена?

Comment: Ну, что никто не работал с докер? Есть какие-нибудь догадки почему на windows 11 докер криво ставится и не работает?

Comment: А wsl2 корректно поставилось?

Comment: @Павел, устанавливался докер без проблем. В инсталляции была галочка WSL, и в настройках есть опция называется "Use the WSL 2 based engine". Ее я отметил галочкой. Не знаю уже, что и делать. Толком даже не поработал, сразу с какими-то проблемами сталкиваюсь, что даже дефолтный контейнер создать не удалось через консоль.

Comment: @Павел, дефолтную команду, которую докер предлагает для копипаста docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started надо запускать с какой-то определенной директории и диска, или это не играет роли?

Comment: @IntegralAL через GUI интерфейс попробуйте поразворачивать

Comment: @Павел, заработало, когда переустановил докер, предварительно убрав галочку Use WSL2 (recommend). Вопрос исчерпан.